# Best way to create virtual machine with 16.04?

Tags: virtualization

I want to install a virtual machine to run Samba with file server and domain controller. The recommendations I read is, do not run a file server and a domain controller on the same system.

As the file server will have higher load I want to virtualize the domain controller. As the domain controller needs to expose services I need to use a bridge for networking, and I prefer DHCP (with static leases).

As I read about KVM before, I looked into [KVM Installation - Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation). To make it short, it did not work, and when searching for solutions I figured out this is obviously no longer the preferred way and the page is outdated.

I then tried to follow [libvirt - Ubuntu help](https://web.archive.org/web/20200326104117/https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html), but I am struggling with connecting to the VM created in order to complete the install - looks like the slave is active, but did not get a network address, and I also was unable to connect to console. Is there a better manual?
Other questions and pages point me to VirtualBox, LXD, Ubuntu Core, or Snappy. Where can I find documentation and - for Snappy - images? What´s your preference and why?

I definitely prefer to do this on the most recent releases.

Answer (score 8):

As always or at least really often - there is no general best way.

What i can offer is a small and not complete list

- [Gnome Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes)
- [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [VMware Workstation](https://my.vmware.com/de/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0%7CPLAYER-1411%7Cproduct_downloads)

Gnome Boxes and Virtualbox should be installable via apt, while the VMware product isn't.

I am using VMware (older Version 11) myself on Ubuntu 16.04 - but it was a mess to get it working on Xenial.

Comment: I suggest installing [VMware Workstation 14.1.1 Player for Linux 64-bit](https://my.vmware.com/de/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0%7CPLAYER-1411%7Cproduct_downloads) which fixes some bugs in version 11 and 12

Comment: You can also download [VMware-Player-14.1.2](http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/player/14.1.2/8497320/linux/core/), which is even newer.